# URL navigation for ajax content

Tags: ajax, url, history

I have a page that gets content from other file through ajax, it works perfect, but when navigated through address bar, it s not working as the event is triggered only on click. I ve searched, but i couldnt find a solution that fits my need. I ve given my code. Somebody help.

```
<a href="#profile" onclick="profile()">Profile</a>
<div id="home-content" class="container-fluid"></div>

<script>
function profile(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions.php",
    data: {action:profile},
        success: function(response)
        {
            $('#home-content').html(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

All i want is when i enter address like home/#profile , profile page has to be loaded and it also should be navigatable, with history entry for 'profile' page

Comment: its work only in onclick...  becasuse you used onclick event only

Comment: or else.. in body onload call the function <body onload="profile()">

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this function

```
 <body onload="profile()">
```

and remove in Onclick funtion

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that is not a problem. what i need is the url navigation of content

Comment: you want directly access the ajax content via url ?